# Create two jar file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a Main class and a folder name "backend" which has one class as well but it doesn't have a method main, I just use methods from this class to the class Main. I need to create two jars: one for Main class and another for the package backend. I've tried the build and only returns a jar. Is there any way to get both?

Comment: It seems you want to create two different projects, each focusing on one jar. Other than that, maybe the build system you use can be configured to produce multiple artifacts. But you have to distinguish ant/maven/gradle for that.

Comment: *I need to create two jars: one for Main class and another for the package backend* Why?